# An unusual request: I need help animating text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the situation. I have three words, but only one is visible with a bracket on each side. Like this:

[Cat]

But then the brackets would slide away from each other, revealing the other two words:

[Dog Cat Cow].

Here it is frame by frame:

1     [Cat]

2   [g Cat C]

3  [og Cat Co]

4 [Dog Cat Cow]

But obviously, I would want the transition between each frame to be much more smoother. Ideally, the word 'Cat' will stay in the same place while the brackets slide away, revealing the other words.

I'm very inexperienced when it comes to animation on the web so I'd appreciate it if you could explain the steps I would need to take to achieve this effect.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this entirely with only CSS.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Center the text and slowly grow the width of the container.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 that wouldn't work! try and see

Comment: Would it be possible to some how trigger the effect? I don't want the effect to start until the user scrolls down and actually sees the text.

Comment: @EricDongJuLee it would be possible, but you're gonna need to ask another question for that!

Comment: @AminJafari It's possible to do in CSS. I don't see why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An hacky no-jquery solution

http://jsfiddle.net/Ccheu/

basically using a div with the text below, and three divs above it.
Left and right ones are opaque (thus hiding left and right parts of the text) and the middle one with no background and empty (thus showing through).
The animation is done by varying the width of the middle one.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        Dog Cat Cow
    </div>
    <div id="mask"><div id="leftm">[</div><div id="middle"></div><div id="rightm">]</div></div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<input type=button value="click me" id="doit">
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}

#content {
    text-align: center;
}

#mask {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#leftm {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
    width: 60px;
}

#middle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}

#rightm {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
doit.onclick = function() {
    var w = 30;
    function step() {
        if (w < 120) {
            middle.style.width = (w++) + "px";
            setTimeout(step, 20);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(step, 200);
};
```

Comment: hats off, brilliant, just brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/8PBW8/1/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#container').animate({width:'100px'},2000);
    $('#text').animate({marginLeft:'0px'},2000);
    $('#wrapper').animate({marginLeft:'-200px'},2000);
});
```

you need to break your text into pieces in order to get it to work, see the code in fiddle, it's pretty clear I suppose, if there was any question about the code, just ask me!

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bracketLeft">[</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="text">Dog Cat Cow</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bracketRight">]</div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS just in case:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:23px;
    line-height:30px;
}
#text{
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-34px;
}
#container{
    width:26px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper{
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic solution that I coded up that uses a `transition` effect. You will probably want to change this to be an `animation` but I didn't feel it would improve my answer all that much for the amount of time required to type out all of the browsers animation types.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXAa8/

The way this works (which can easily be changed), is when you hover over the `logo div`, the two `expand divs` then grow in width. The left `expand div` has text direction turned on to be `rtl` so the right of the text will be shown first.

The HTML

```
<div class="logo">
    <div class="expand left">Dog</div>
    <div class="visible">Cat</div>
    <div class="expand right">Cow</div>
</div>
```

The Style Sheet

```
.logo {
    width: 100%;
}
.logo .expand {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 0.5s linear;
}
.logo:hover .expand {
    width: 30px;   
}
.logo > div {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}
.logo .expand.left {
    direction: rtl;
}
```